# Hide HTML element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to hide an element based on a role. (The roles are "Teacher" and "Student")
This is the element I want to hide if a role is Student.

`tab.html`

```
<a href="/profile" class="nav-item nav-link">Update</a>

<script src="{{ url_for('jquery', filename='jquery/profile/tab.js') }}"></script> //to access the .js file
```

I like to create a function in `tab.js` that will hide the element above if the role is "Student" but I do not have that much idea since I have no experience with JQuery

Comment: What is a _role_ in all this? How does your code know what _role_ is involved?

Answer (score -1):

you can using jQuery hide() Method

for example:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
});
```

Comment: what button? I see no button in the question nor a reference to that.

Comment: What should I put in the "button" part? Is it the button before I access the <a href="/profile" class="nav-item nav-link">Update</a> element?